# ¿Cómo podemos valorar el mínimo de errores acumulados para editar?

Tags: discusión

Es algo de lo que se ha hablado mucho, pero de todo lo leído, creo no he conseguido sacar una conclusión medianamente clara.

Al final del día, por una cosa u otra terminas pasando por el sitio, ya sea *SOes o SO (StackOverflow en español o inglés)*, consultas, lees, respondes, preguntas, valoras... y si ves algo que corregir, corriges. Siempre busco algo de criterio en las correcciones a hacer. Formatear código para mejorar la lectura, correcciones de ortografía, etc.

Está claro que todos tenemos errores y a todos nos puede ocurrir *(con total seguridad al terminar de redactar este texto tendré faltas de ortografía o gramaticales)*, pero si te encuentras una pregunta o respuesta que acumula varias correcciones, la editas y aprovechando esa edición le das algo de formato.

Si la pregunta o respuesta no cumple con lo mínimo requerido, ni siquiera me planteo perder tiempo en editar, ya que será cerrada o eliminada.

En más de una pregunta, y más de un comentario, recuerdo haber leído que todas estas aportaciones no solo son positivas, sino que aportan valor al sitio y ayudan de cara al futuro del sitio para que otros puedan encontrar ayuda.

Hoy me ha llamado la atención la palabra *Analitycs* en la siguiente pregunta:

- [Implementar Google Analytics en Zend Framework 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75654)

Un error que suelo ver con frecuencia, es que en vez de ser *Analitics (con i latina luego de la ele)* es *Analytics (con **ye** o **y griega**)*.

Entro y veo una [corrección aprobada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/75654/revisions), la abro y la reviso. Se ha editado el título y tiene algo más que mejorar, la voy a editar.

[Realizo las correcciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/47681) que creo oportunas y guardo los cambios.

Viendo la cantidad de cambios mínimos que se realizan y son aprobados, realmente me extrañó que se rechazaran los cambios.

Vuelvo a hacer la [segunda edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/47702), y dejo el comentario:

> *Si no se elimina la pregunta, no creo que queramos texto con faltas de ortografía y nombres mal escritos...*

Se repite la misma valoración, rechazando de nuevo estos cambios.

... y de ahí que quiera exponer estas preguntas:

*Para ser ediciones aprobadas*:

> **¿Cómo podemos valorar el mínimo de *errores* acumulados para editar?**

... y esta otra, si existiera un orden:

> ¿Qué tipo de ediciones prevalecen, formateo de código, formato de texto, mejoras de comprensión o correcciones de ortografía?

*Si me he dejado algo atrás comenten y edito.*

---

Para poner algo de contexto, he puesto un ejemplo (ficticio) bastante extremo y soluciones posibles. ¿Cuáles serían susceptibles de ser aprobadas y cuáles no? Además, ¿Cuál de las soluciones, sería susceptible de recibir una re-edición?

#### Ejemplo 1

Uno de los principales problemas (tratandose en PHP6) register_globals.uno de los metodos estandar utilizados para ebitar register_globals es utilizar los array $_REQUEST,$_GET o $_POST. la forma correcta de acerlo seria mediante filtros.en vez de usar esto:$user=$_POST["username"];se deveria acer:$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);incluso solo:$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');

#### Solución 1

Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de PHP) es register_globals. Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar register_globals es utilizar los array's $_REQUEST, $_GE o $_POST.
La forma correcta de hacerlo sería mediante filtros.
En vez de usar esto: $user = $_POST["username"];
Se debería hacer: $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
Incluso sólo: $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');

#### Solución 2

Uno de los principales problemas (tratandose de PHP6) es register_globals. uno de los metodos estandar utilizados para ebitar register_globals es utilizar los array $_REQUEST, $_GET o $_POST.

la forma "correcta" de acerlo seria mediante filtros.

En vez de usar esto:
$user = $_POST["username"];

Se deveria acer:
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Incluso solo:
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');

#### Solución 3

Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de PHP6) es register_globals. Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar register_globals es utilizar los arrays $_REQUEST, $_GET o $_POST.

La forma "correcta" de hacerlo sería mediante filtros.

En vez de usar esto:
$user = $_POST["username"];

Se debería hacer:
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Incluso sólo:
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');

#### Solución 4

Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de `PHP6`) es `register_globals`. Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar `register_globals` es utilizar los `array's` `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` o `$_POST`.

La forma *correcta* de hacerlo sería mediante filtros.

En vez de usar esto: `$user = $_POST["username"];`

Se debería hacer:`$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Incluso sólo: `$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');`

#### Solución 5

Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de `PHP6`) es `register_globals`. Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar `register_globals` es utilizar los `array's` `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` o `$_POST`.
La forma *correcta* de hacerlo sería mediante filtros.
En vez de usar esto: `$user = $_POST["username"];`
Se debería hacer:`$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`
Incluso sólo: `$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');`

#### Solución 6

Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de *PHP6*) es `register_globals`. Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar `register_globals` es utilizar los *arrays* `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` o `$_POST`.

La forma *correcta* de hacerlo seria mediante filtros.

En vez de usar esto:

```php
$user = $_POST["username"];
```

Se debería hacer:

```php
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Incluso sólo:

```php
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
```

Comment: No digo que haya sido el motivo del rechazo (cada quién sabrá), pero quizás el hecho de haber puesto `Google` o `hosting` como código puede haber contribuido a no estar predispuesto a aprobarla. No obstante, el tema de fondo que estás planteando me parece excelente, y recomendaría sacar este formato de tu pregunta, para poder enfocarnos en una discusión mucho más interesante.

Comment: Además, en tus ejemplos no se está considerando al título de la pregunta (que para mí tiene un valor mucho mayor), y estaría bueno poner algún ejemplo que no deje mal a la pregunta, y que corrija un error de de ortografía en el título.

Comment: Eh @Mariano, este es un ejemplo de lo que yo llamaría _"un taller"_: ejemplos prácticos para mejorar una habilidad o competencia específica. Por otro lado, no pienso justificar mis votos, pero creo que el objetivo de la edición es mejorar la comprensión y no tanto la estética. La comprensión de una pregunta no mejora si se lee `Google` en vez de Google. No hablo de los casos específicos expuestos, solo expongo mi criterio. La idea es excelente y puede usarse para mejorar los criterios de cierre de preguntas. PD, yo siempre olvido los títulos.

Comment: @Mariano pensé en lo de los títulos, y coincido en que son de gran valor, pero como la gran mayoría d las ediciones se realizan en el cuerpo de la propia pregunta/respuesta lo enfoqué de esta forma. No obstante, le doy un pensada para ver como lo incorporo. Se aceptan sugerencias, esto es para todos.

Comment: @toledano quiero dejar una cosa clara, en absoluto estoy solicitando justificación de nadie, puedo llegar a entender los motivos a pesar de no estar de acuerdo con la decisión. Realmente lo que intento es comprender a partir de que criterios (comunes) uso mi tiempo en ediciones que aporten bien al sitio, y para eso debe existir un mínimo en el que basarse para decidir, esta si, o esta no. Por ejemplo, como bien expones, un criterio es mejorar la comprensión y no la estética, por lo que se puede establecer entonces que si la edición es meramente estética, no se aprobará. Es un punto de partida.

Comment: @OscarR Yo creo que es cuestión del revisor que te toca... Por ejemplo, si haces una edición mejorando la comprensión, y te toca un revisor que se frustra al ver una mala estética, será rechazada de igual manera.

Comment: @ArtEze se que es un tema complejo, intervienen muchas variables, y no se ven igual por la mañana fresco, que cuando llevas todo el día liado. Suele cambiar nuestra perspectiva conforme avanza el día. Pero las ediciones entiendo que no se deben aprobar o rechazar según me parezca bueno o malo un aspecto de la edición. Sino valorar que se ha mejorado de forma global, el tiempo en dar a _Aceptar_ o _Rechazar_ es el mismo. Si ha mejorado un 30% comprensión... 9% estética ¿Hemos ganado algo? Creo que si.

Comment: Pienso que se pueden crear segmentos de tipos de edición _(Título, Comprensión, estética, ortografía, formato...)_ y darle un cierto peso o valor a cada uno de ellos para contar con una guía que ayude a los usuarios a decidir si entrar a realizar ediciones, y que ayude a valorar esas revisiones a los _Revisores_, de igual forma que se hace para valorar si una pregunta es apta o no para ser publicada en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente pienso que la pregunta del *Zend Framework* es ***Demasiado amplia***, por lo que debería ser cerrada.

Dicho esto, dejo el original y luego la manera en cómo la editaría yo:

Pregunta original:

> `Uno de los principales problemas (tratandose en PHP6) register_globals.uno de los metodos estandar utilizados para ebitar register_globals es utilizar los array $_REQUEST,$_GET o $_POST. la forma correcta de acerlo seria mediante filtros.en vez de usar esto:$user=$_POST["username"];se deveria acer:$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);incluso solo:$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');`

Formato de código:

> `` Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de _PHP, que en este caso se usa la versión 6_) es el de `register_globals`. ``
>
> `` Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar `register_globals` es utilizar los arrays `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` o `$_POST`. La forma correcta de hacerlo sería mediante filtros. ``
>
> `En vez de usar esto:`
>
> ```php
>     $user=$_POST["username"];
> ```
>
> `Se debería hacer:`
>
> ```php
>     $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
> ```
>
> `Además, también se podría hacer esto:`
>
> ```php
>     $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
> ```
>
> `<br/>`

El resultado de mi supuesta edición:

> Uno de los principales problemas (tratándose de *PHP, que en este caso se usa la versión 6*) es el de `register_globals`.
>
> Uno de los métodos estándar utilizados para evitar `register_globals` es utilizar los arrays `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` o `$_POST`. La forma correcta de hacerlo sería mediante filtros.
>
> En vez de usar esto:
>
> ```php
> $user=$_POST["username"];
> ```
>
> Se debería hacer:
>
> ```php
> $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
> ```
>
> Además, también se podría hacer esto:
>
> ```php
> $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
> ```

Yo no soy de aprobar o rechazar... En vez de eso, lo que frecuentemente hago es **Mejorar edición**: Yo aprobaría todas las soluciones, y editando la sugerencia, **menos la 1**, ya que no agrega espacios para los párrafos.

Yo prefiero los nombres propios (sustantivos) como **PHP**, o tecnicismos en inglés, en itálica, *PHP* (`_PHP_`) en vez de formato de código, `PHP` (`` `PHP` ``), pero cuando se trata de código fuente, ahí sí, en formato de código, como esto `$variable` (`` `$variable` ``).

[La edición de **@IvanBotero**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/75654/revisions) no fue aprobada, él puede editar inmediatamente, porque tiene [una reputación mayor a 2000](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Además, no es que la edición tuya estuviera mal, es que te tocó un revisor que suele rechazar con mayor frecuencia las ediciones sugeridas, que es **@toledano**... Con respecto a **@Shaz**, él suele aprobar las ediciones, pero justo encontró una en que no estaba de acuerdo... Al ver nuevamente la misma edición, habrán pensado, *"Esta ya la rechacé, creo que debería rechazarla denuevo"*.

Comment: Creo que `_PHP6_` sería mejor convertirla a `[tag:php6]` lo que resulta en [tag:php6]...

Comment: @toledano Sí, es buena idea.

Comment: Pues a mí el uso de `[tag:XX]` no me gusta demasiado, me parece que resalta algo que no es necesario y genera un enlace que no es útil. Como mucho añadiría un enlace a un lenguaje si es una versión concreta y hay algo relevante a destacar. Un enlace a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php6 en el ámbito de una pregunta o respuesta no creo que aporte nada, pues simplemente ofrece una lista de preguntas similares.

Comment: @ArtEze por otra parte, es interesante el tema planteado sobre como editar los sustantivos y los tecnicismos, lo tendré en cuenta. Gracias por aportar tu punto de vista.